# Goodwillie tower of $\Omega^n$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory

What are layers of the Goodwillie tower of the functor "n-th iterated loop space" from based spaces to based spaces? I know the answer for n=0.

Comment: As $\Omega^n$ preserves homotopy pullbacks, the derivatives of $\Omega^n$ will just be $\Omega^n$ of the derivatives of the identity.

Comment: @NeilStrickland Thank you very much, Neil! It was pretty obvious, I am ashamed. In fact, I am looking for a functor, whose Goodwillie tower looks like the one for identity, but the Lie operad is replaced with the (suspension spectrum of) little cubes operad.